# Having problems parsing file with multiple blank lines and extra spaces

Tags: c, parsing, newline, whitespace, strtok

Here is part of the file I am trying to parse:

```
flr2941 flr2822 flr118 flr833 flr2283 flr256 flr232
flr610 wrn448 flr1541 wrn104 wrn443 flr2680 wrn312 flr360

flr1875 flr1449 wrn456 flr549
flr297
flr122 flr2034 wrn247 wrn99 flr549 flr1606 wrn70 flr405 flr2167 wrn18 flr1976 wrn203
flr2350 flr297 flr1662 flr1747 wrn312
flr987 wrn111 flr1935
flr1552 wrn202 flr549 wrn458 flr2822 flr2900
flr1854 wrn104 flr117 flr2941
flr117 flr286 flr1454
flr2935 flr2118
 flr1662 flr2936 flr1388 wrn472 wrn19 flr117
flr1971 flr1382 flr117 wrn472 flr878 wrn203 flr662 flr1381 wrn124 flr424

flr2315 wrn70 flr2910 flr1661 flr2118 flr302
 flr1455 flr795
flr700 flr1655 wrn479 flr117
```

I am trying to print out either "flrXYZ" or "wrnXYZ" to show that I've successfully parsed the words in each file. The code for this is:

```
/* Loop through each line in the file*/
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        /* Slice each word and if not a "\n", print it */
        tempToken = strtok(buffer, " ");
        while(tempToken != NULL) {
            stringLength = strlen(tempToken);
            printf("%s Count: %d\n", tempToken, stringLength);
            tempToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
```

I added a count to each token to see what was going on and I got some interesting results but I can't seem to pinpoint exactly where the problem is.  Here is a piece of random output from the command line (data file is ~45,000 lines long):

```
wrn70 Count: 5
flr255
 Count: 7

 Count: 1
flr1857
 Count: 8
flr2941
 Count: 8
flr2404
 Count: 8
wrn477 Count: 6

 Count: 1
flr549
 Count: 7
flr117 Count: 6
flr351 Count: 6
flr1854
 Count: 8

 Count: 1
```

An important point I am trying to make is this file has random areas where there are extra newline characters and white spaces. How can I parse the file so that it ignores any extra white spaces or newline characters?

Comment: I think you should use `tempToken = strtok(buffer, " \n");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a newline `\n` to the delimiter argument in both calls to `strtok()`:

```
tempToken = strtok(buffer, " \n");
```

Remember, `fgets()` includes the newline in the line it reads, and `strtok()` was told to split on spaces, so the newline was included with the words.

---

> I can't quite wrap my head around how the `strtok()` function can detect consecutive spaces or newlines. It is saying white space and newline are both delimiters?

The calls are saying that either blank or newline (which is not the same as white space; `isblank()` recognizes space `' '` and tab '`\t'`; `isspace()` recognizes form feed `'\f'`, carriage return `'\r'`, newline `'\n'` and vertical tab `'\v'` as well as space and tab) mark the end of the tokens that `strtok()` is to recognize.  `strtok()` is defined to treat multiple characters from the delimiters as equivalent to one.  And remember that `strtok()` destroys the input string by writing null bytes `'\0'` at the ends of tokens, and zaps the delimiter so you can't tell what the delimiter was unless you've made a copy of the string or something similar.

You can read the specification of [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) to see what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It solved the problem. But I can't quite wrap my head around how the strtok function can detect consecutive spaces or newlines. It is saying white space and newline are both delimiters?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031496/1679849) will fix your problem.

But do the line breaks in your data file actually signify anything?

If not, and you are only interested in retrieving the alphanumeric tokens one after another, then it would make more sense to use `fscanf()` instead. This will make your code more compact and readable. (The `"%s"` format string implicitly disregards all white space characters.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  FILE *file;
  char buffer[100];
  int stringLength;
  file = fopen("my_data.dat","r");
  while (fscanf(file,"%99s", buffer) != EOF) {
    stringLength = strlen(buffer);
    printf("%s Count: %d\n", buffer, stringLength);
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wondered if there was a more efficient way than the solution I had come up with.

Comment: Plus one for thinking out of the box.  And minus one to SO for rejecting comments that start `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

For strtok instead of passing only space add even '\n' i.e, let the second parameter to strtok be " \n". Since only space is given as delimiter you are getting even newline as the parsed string. It works fine if there is many spaces and many newline between two words.